# ModRewrite combine sites to one

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

Hi I am having some issues configuring rewrites which have fairly complex requirements

browsing (www.)A.com should => www.B.com

browsing (www.)A.com/{anything}/blah/foo/yes should => {anything}.B.com/blah/foo/yes

I had the root rewrite working but am having trouble getting the two rules to work simultaneously.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?A\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.B.com [NC,R=301]
Redirect /surveys/ http://surveys.B.com/
```

This is me trying to redirect the subdir to a subdomain direct rather than using regexes.

Comment: What is your current rewrite configuration?

Comment: Added above Tero

Comment: You are mixing `Rewrite*` (mod_rewrite) and `Redirect` (mod_alias) directives here. You should use only either one, as the results of mixed use aren't well defined. In your case, you should use only `Rewrite*` directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use **Redirect** statement to do that, but only **RewriteRule**.  Something like that should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?A\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.B.com [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ http://$1.B.com$2 [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you - The first rule works perfectly, but the second is not matching any urls, strangely. I just tried this on a different site and still nothing is matching. I'm going to try and increase the Apache log level

Comment: I think I spotted an error in my last rule, I just edited it.  If the rule still doesn't work, yes, increasing the log level is a good way.  Beware that it is done differently with apache 2.2 and 2.4.  Not sure which one you're using.

Comment: Hi I'm using Apache 2.2 - I've basically spent hours getting this to work, and after much head scratching I have a working solution: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?A\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ http://$1.B.co.uk$2 [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.B.co.uk [NC,R=301]` - it seems if I have the order of rules the other way round, matching of the root url does not work.

Comment: Notice the rule for the subdomain rewrite does not contain a `/` at the beginning. If that is there, the rule does not match

Comment: That seems a bit weird to me... you need the **/** at the beginning of the second rule.  And beware that if you don't repeat the **RewriteCond** the second rule can match for any HTTP_HOST.  At the end, what is the solution that is working for you, the one in your comment or the one in your edit?